# How to use CSS Class and ID selectors

Tags: html, css

I am new to css and i have been trying to come up with a nice looking homepage but got confused with the right selectors to use. 
I have designed the buttons very well using unordered lists but the lists in the other content also inherit the formats of the buttons.

how should i assign a one class or two  to the unorderd button list?
many thanks!
i want the class to have the following code.
here is the code i used for the buttons.

```
/* button styling */

ul {
 list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

a {
  background: #404853;
  background: linear-gradient(#687587, #404853);
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 38px;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:hover {
  background: #454d59;
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: #d0d2d5;
}

li:first-child a {
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

li:last-child a {
  border-right: none;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should scope your selector to make them more explicit.

A good way is, if your `ul` is in a `header` element:

```
header ul {}
header ul li {}
```

Or also, if it is in some element with id `#navigation`:

```
#navigation ul {}
#navigation ul li {}
```

This will affect all `ul` elements inside `header` or `#navigation`.

Another way is to add an ID to your unsorted list in your html:

```
<ul id="navigation">
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

In this case you could use just that ID in your selector:

```
ul#navigation {}
ul#navigation li {}
```

Or just:

```
#navigation {}
#navigation li {}
```

Comment: need to mention that `header ul` means that all found `<ul>` tags would use that styles. Same with `header ul li`, this will apply to all `<li>` elements found in each `<ul>` under `<header>` tag.

Comment: Thanks For answering, it all makes sense. But please help me and put the above code in the question for my list in the #navigation.

Comment: I don't know about your HTML structure, you just posted CSS. You can still edit your answer and add that info to see how your HTML looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so as I think you know, you are using very broad selectors here - which is of course the reason why all of your `<li>` tags are appearing the same, site-wide.

As you say, `class`es, or even `id`s could be used to help here.

Although [there is some debate](https://www.google.com/search?q=dont%20use%20ids%20in%20css%20selectors) over whether you should use `id`s at all in CSS, I will show you examples of both.

**IDs:**

First rule of IDs: **IDs must be unique to the page!**.

This doesn't mean you can't reuse the ID on other pages within your site, but you must ensure that, per page load, your IDs are unique. In CSS selectors, an ID selector is decorated with a `#`.

**Example:**

*HTML:*

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li>Text 1</li>
    <li>Text 2</li>
    <li>Text 3</li>
</ul>
```

*CSS:*

```
/* This selector will select the element with the "myList" ID,
   in this case, the <ul> tag in the above example.
   Keep in mind, it isn't selecting the <li> tags */
#myList
{
   float: left;
}

/* The following style selects all
   <li> tags WITHIN any element with the "myList" ID */
#myList li
{
   font-weight:bold;
}
```

**Classes:**

Classes are, for the most part, the same as IDs but do not have to be unique to a certain page. Classes are decorated with a `.` (period).

*HTML:*

```
<ul class="myList">
    <li>Text 1</li>
    <li class="selected">Text 2</li>
    <li>Text 3</li>
</ul>
```

*CSS:*

```
/* same as before, but now we are targeting a class */
.myList
{
   float: left;
}

/* as you can see, there is no difference in the usage here. */
.myList li
{
   color:blue;
}

/* if you prefix the class or ID name with an element tag
   (in this case, li for the <li> element), then the selector will
   only select elements with the specified ID/Class, that is of
   that element type.
   In this example, the following selector means:
   "Select all <li> tags that have the class 'selected'"
   This is useful, say, in a navigation bar. */
li.selected
{
    /* this will overwrite the
       color attribute defined in the 
       ".myList li" style, in this case,
       to highlight that the selected item is green */
    color:green;
}
```

**JSFiddle: (Very useful site)**
http://jsfiddle.net/fSsdf/

I hope this helps!

Comment: Great answer. In addition to this, if the OP uses HTML5 (and why he shouldn't) he could also put the navigation ul inside a <nav> and then target only the navigational elements with 'nav ul'.

Comment: Thanks For answering, it all makes sense. But please help me and put the above code in the question for my list in one id.

Comment: @RichardFreeman no problem. Sorry, I am travelling at the moment and am not really able to edit my answer. Sorry... Hopefully the other answers have helped enough :)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<ul class="class1">
 <li>Content</li>
 <li>Content</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.class1{
 float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, i appreciate. it all helps.